# Current hardware and software for converting family tapes to digital. Most of the existing links are out of date/not manufactured. I have a Mac M3

Tags: video-capture

Current hardware and software for converting family tapes to digital please.  Many of the existing links appear out of date/not manufactured.  I have a Mac M3.

Answer (score 0):

It would probably be easier, cheaper  & better quality to get the conversions done by a specialist. You can then edit in iMovie or even [DaVinci Resolve](https://www.blackmagicdesign.com/products/davinciresolve/) [freeware for non-pro use.]